Difference in Output Between Two Similar C++ Codes with Nested Loops and transform
I'm experiencing a strange issue with two similar pieces of C++ code that are supposed to perform the same task but yield different results.
The problem is around the inner loop statement .
While implementing the solution,I came across this issue:-
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> arr(n);
        REP(i, 0, n){
            cin >> arr[i];
        }

        vector<int> dup = arr;
        int maxVal = INT_MIN;
        REP(i, 0, n){
            if (arr[i] > maxVal){
                maxVal = arr[i];
            }
            if (arr[i] < maxVal){
                arr[i] = maxVal;
            }
        }

        REP(i, 0, n){
            dup[i] = arr[i] - dup[i];
        }

        int ans = 0;
        sort(dup.begin(), dup.end());

        REP(i, 0, n){
            if (dup[i] != 0){
                ans += (n - i + 1) * dup[i];

               //This inner loop

                for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
                    dup[j] -= dup[i];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << ans << "\n";
    }
    return 0;


While I was able to get the correct result by replacing the inner loop with transform function ,but I am not able to understand why doesn't this work .The code gives the same answer even after I remove the inner loop ,as if the inner loop is not even doing anything.
I am not a expert or something in codeforces but I have solved a good amount of problems involving loops and arrays ,here I am really clueless about the issue .
Could someone help me understand why the first version of the code doesn't produce the correct result? Is there a logical error in how I am updating the dup vector?
Also this the transform function which I am talking about :-
transform(dup.begin() + i, dup.end(), dup.begin() + i,
                         [value = dup[i]](int x) { return x - value; });


Please read [ask]. All information necessary to understand your problem should be in the question itself if possible, not in an external link.

@AndrewYim ,the only link I have shared is the original question ,which has nothing to do with my doubt .

Either a) the link isn't relevant to your question, in which case you should delete it for simplicity (and probably trim your code down to a [mre]), or b), it is relevant and you should expand on it on your question. Which course of action is better will vary depending on how you feel about the situation.

The transform version isn't equivalent to the loop you marked as This inner loop. Time to use a debugger and watch the value that you are subtracting.
